# How can run the following code on multiple Excel sheets?

Tags: windows, macos, vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a code which I would like to use on multiple sheets, except one sheet. But applying the code to alle sheets is also fine.
Here is the code that I would like to adjust. I am have currently applied it to Excel 2011 in OS X , but I would like to use it for Excel 2010 in Windows.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then

Dim the_selection As String
Dim month_in_review As String

the_selection = Sheet1.Range("A1")

    Dim Rep As Integer
    For Rep = 2 To 379
        the_column = GetColumnLetter_ByInteger(Rep)
        month_in_review = Sheet1.Range(the_column & "1")
            If the_selection = month_in_review Then
            Sheet1.Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
            Else
            Sheet1.Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
            End If
    Next Rep

End If
End Sub
```

In the module I have the following code:

```
Public Function GetColumnLetter_ByInteger(what_number As Integer) As String
GetColumnLetter_ByInteger = ""

MyColumn_Integer = what_number

    If MyColumn_Ineger <= 26 Then
        column_letter = ChrW(64 + MyColumn_Integer)
    End If


If MyColumn_Integer > 26 Then
    column_letter = ChrW(Int((MyColumn_Integer - 1) / 26) + 64) & ChrW(((MyColumn_Integer - 1) Mod 26) + 65)

End If

GetColumnLetter_ByInteger = column_letter

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking for one sheet to detect the change in cell "A1" and then to hide/unhide columns on multiple sheets then the prior answers to your question will serve you nicely.

If, on the other hand, you're asking to detect a change in cell "A1" on any sheet and then to hide/unhide columns on just the changed sheet, then the code below will work for you. It accesses the `Workbook_SheetChanged` event at Workbook level.

A few points about your code:

1. You can reference cells using their integer or address values with the `.Cell` property, so `Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)` is the same as `Sheet1.Cells(1, "A")`.  The same applies to the `.Columns` property. So there's no real need to convert your integer values to a string. See @Florent B's answer for a good example of this.
2. Wherever possible, minimise looping sheet interactions as these are very time-consuming. So rather than loop through the columns and hide/unhide each one individually, you could assign them to ranges within your loop and then hide/unhide the ranges all in one go at the end of your loop. If you must interact with the sheet on each iteration of your loop, then set the `Application.ScreenUpdating` property to false before the start of your loop. There's an example of this property in the sample code below.

Put this in your `Workbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Const TARGET_ADDRESS As String = "A1"
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim hiddenCols As Range
    Dim unhiddenCols As Range
    Dim selectedMonth As String
    Dim monthInReview As String
    Dim c As Integer

    'Ignore event if not a target worksheet
    If Sh.Name = "Not Wanted" Then Exit Sub

    'Ignore event if not in target range
    Set cell = Target.Cells(1)
    If cell.Address(False, False) <> TARGET_ADDRESS Then Exit Sub

    'Criteria met, so handle event
    selectedMonth = CStr(cell.Value)
    For c = 2 To 379
        Set cell = Sh.Cells(1, c)
        monthInReview = CStr(cell.Value)
        'Add cell to hidden or unhidden ranges
        If monthInReview = selectedMonth Then
            If unhiddenCols Is Nothing Then
                Set unhiddenCols = cell
            Else
                Set unhiddenCols = Union(unhiddenCols, cell)
            End If
        Else
            If hiddenCols Is Nothing Then
                Set hiddenCols = cell
            Else
                Set hiddenCols = Union(hiddenCols, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Hide and unhide the cells
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'not really needed here but given as example
    If Not unhiddenCols Is Nothing Then
        unhiddenCols.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
    If Not hiddenCols Is Nothing Then
        hiddenCols.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for each loop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) to loop through all the Worksheets, and check the worksheet name if it should be skipped. Then apply your code onto the sheet selected.

Something like:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Skip Sheet" Then
            Dim the_selection As String
            Dim month_in_review As String

            the_selection = ws.Range("A1")

            Dim Rep As Integer
            For Rep = 2 To 379
                the_column = GetColumnLetter_ByInteger(Rep)
                month_in_review = ws.Range(the_column & "1")
                If the_selection = month_in_review Then
                    ws.Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
                    Else
                    ws.Range(the_column & ":" & the_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
                    End If
            Next Rep
        End If
    Next ws
End If
End Sub
```

I wasn't entirely sure what you wished to achieve, so i put ws in the place of `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 0):

This example will show/hide the columns in all the other sheets if the first cell of the column match/differ with the cell A1 of the sheet where this code is placed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  ' exit if not cell A1
  If Target.row <> 1 Or Target.column <> 1 Then Exit Sub

  Dim sheet As Worksheet
  Dim the_selection As String
  Dim month_in_review As String
  Dim column As Integer

  the_selection = Target.Value

  ' iterate all the sheets
  For Each sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    ' skip this sheet
    If Not sheet Is Me Then

      ' iterate the columns
      For column = 2 To 379

        ' get the first cell of the column
        month_in_review = sheet.Cells(1, column).Value

        ' hide or show the column if it's a match or not
        sheet.Columns(column).Hidden = month_in_review <> the_selection
      Next

    End If
  Next

End Sub
```